# Designing function callbacks with Async calls

Tags: javascript

What is the best practice when designing code that can work with async functions inside callback functions, here is a simplified view of the problem.

---

There is this update functions that makes some async function calls to update some data to some kind of storage.

```
function update(){
  asyncfn(arg, () => {// Callback code});
}
```

then there are these two buttons to call the update function

```
Updatebtn.onClick = update;

UpdateDisplaybtn.onClick = () => {
  update();
  displayUpdatedData();
}
```

The second button will cause problems as the displayUpdatedData() will be called before the update() is truly finished as it has an async function call that will not be finished, also i can not specify my own callback in update() as it is used as a callback to the onClick event.

I don't know much about promises but what i know that the async functions i use does not support them.

I am not looking for some kind of workaround, i am looking for the best practice in a situation like this.

---

**UPDATE**

After learning that the best practice is using promises i used this YouTube playlist "[JavaScript Promises](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6bKLPQvPRNNE65kBL62mVfx)" by The Coding Train to learn about them which was very good and i wanted to share it with anyone who want to learn about Promises.

Comment: Could you just make the anonymous function for the `UpdateDisplaybtn.onClick` an `async` function as well and then `await` the `update()` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with a function that only accepts a call back, you can wrap it inside of a promise so you can leverage `async` / `await`. If the function already returns a promise, you can just use the `async` / `await` without having to wrap it.

Doing it this way, you can still have your sequential execution of your `update` and `displayUpdatedData` functions by simply putting them within an `async` function and `awaiting` them.

```js
function callbackFunction (cb) {
  // ... stuff is happening
  cb('Data from the callback func');
}

async function update() {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    callbackFunction( (data) => {
      resolve(data); // or reject(); if failure
    });
    
  });
}

const doThings = async () => {
  const result = await update();
  console.log(result);
  // TODO: Display data from the result
};

doThings();
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you are looking for best practices, I highly recommend you familiarize yourself with promises. Javascript now supports the async / await syntax, which allows you to await the response of promises, but lets you write your code more or less like an ordinary function. I know you are saying that the async functions you want to use require callbacks, and do not support promises, but you can convert a callback based function to a promise based one (promisify) using libraries like bluebird, or if you are in node, it has a native promisify function of its own.

So then you would end up with something like this:

```
import cbFn from 'cbFn'; //import or require your callback based function
import {promisify} from 'util';

const pFn = promisify(cbFn);

async function update() {
  await pFn()
}

...

UpdateDisplaybtn.onClick = async () => {
  await update();
  await displayUpdatedData() //await only needed if displayUpdatedData is also async / a promise
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the term 'syntactical sugar' (TypeScript term). `async` / `await` is 100% native JS syntax.

Comment: Updated. I'm still used to thinking about it in terms of when we had to have transpilers for async / await